# QDevelop Qt IDE in Ubuntu 10.04 LTS Lucid Lynx qwt

Tags: build, qt4, ubuntu-10.04, qwt

I am having an issue using the QDevelop, Qt IDE (Qt version 4.6.2) in Ubuntu 10.04 LTS Lucid Lynx. The code I am trying to work with was transfered from a newer 64bit laptop to my 32 bit laptop. Both systems are running the same version of Ubuntu and Qt IDE. When I try building the code I get a long list of errors, which I don't really want to post here but I will at the end of my text. Any help would be greatly appreciated. For whatever reason, my blocks of text are getting cut off. I am using the "< pre>insert text here< slashpre> white space retainer trick, what am I doing wrong? Ok my build chunk of text is not being formatted properly using the pre slashpre html thingies.. The formating of this post is getting all messed up! :|

Email I sent my college:

```
I installed the 32bit version of qwt-5.2.1 and it still isn’t building, I get the same errors. 

Attached are my .pro and make files as well as buildoutput.txt showing the results of my build.

See if you see anything wrong with any of the information below:

Checking paths:

In the myPico.pro file there is a line: LIBS += -L/usr/local/qwt-5.2.1/lib -lqwt-qt4 (This is 32bit, I found you can type “file” then space and a file name, it will give you information about the file including if it’s 32bit or 64bit. See note below.)

Inside /usr/local/qwt-5.2.1/lib I have three items that are teal: libqwt.so, libqwt.so.5 and libqwt.so.5.2 and one green item: libqwt.so.5.2.1. They all point to libqwt.so.5.2.1 and it’s 32bit.

Inside the Makefile, the line INCPATH everything seems ok, but I don’t understand the last part of the line: “-I/usr/include/qt4 -Ibuild  -Ibuild” When I go to /usr/include/qt4 I don’t see anything that says build. Could this be an issue?

In searching the web for solutions I see a lot of people having the same issue but their solutions are cryptic/Band-Aid short cuts.

Note: I thought of a possible issue. You had me copy the libs from your system and then we found out they were 64 bit. I installed the 32 bit ones but I don’t know if that removed what we copied manually. So I am trying to figure out where we copied those libs to. Ok I found it (/usr/local/qwt-5.2.1/lib) and they’re 32 bit, so installing the 32 bit overwrote the 64bit versions.
```

.pro file:

```
TEMPLATE = app
QT = gui core
CONFIG += qt warn_on console debug
DESTDIR = bin
OBJECTS_DIR = build
MOC_DIR = build
UI_DIR = build
FORMS = ui/mainwindow.ui
HEADERS = src/mainwindowimpl.h src/picofunctions.h src/Thread.h
SOURCES = src/mainwindowimpl.cpp src/main.cpp src/picofunctions.cpp src/Thread.cpp
LIBS += -L/usr/local/qwt-5.2.1/lib -lqwt-qt4
```

Makefile:

#############################################################################
# Makefile for building: bin/myPico
# Generated by qmake (2.01a) (Qt 4.6.2) on: Mon Nov 22 10:56:19 2010
# Project:  myPico.pro
# Template: app
# Command: /usr/bin/qmake-qt4 -unix -o Makefile myPico.pro
#############################################################################

####### Compiler, tools and options

CC            = gcc
CXX           = g++
DEFINES       = -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED
CFLAGS        = -pipe -g -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT $(DEFINES)
CXXFLAGS      = -pipe -g -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT $(DEFINES)
INCPATH       = -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -Ibuild -Ibuild
LINK          = g++
LFLAGS        = 
LIBS          = $(SUBLIBS)  -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/qwt-5.2.1/lib -lqwt-qt4 -lQtGui -lQtCore -lpthread 
AR            = ar cqs
RANLIB        = 
QMAKE         = /usr/bin/qmake-qt4
TAR           = tar -cf
COMPRESS      = gzip -9f
COPY          = cp -f
SED           = sed
COPY_FILE     = $(COPY)
COPY_DIR      = $(COPY) -r
STRIP         = strip
INSTALL_FILE  = install -m 644 -p
INSTALL_DIR   = $(COPY_DIR)
INSTALL_PROGRAM = install -m 755 -p
DEL_FILE      = rm -f
SYMLINK       = ln -f -s
DEL_DIR       = rmdir
MOVE          = mv -f
CHK_DIR_EXISTS= test -d
MKDIR         = mkdir -p

####### Output directory

OBJECTS_DIR   = build/

####### Files

SOURCES       = src/mainwindowimpl.cpp \
        src/main.cpp \
        src/picofunctions.cpp \
        src/Thread.cpp build/moc_mainwindowimpl.cpp
OBJECTS       = build/mainwindowimpl.o \
        build/main.o \
        build/picofunctions.o \
        build/Thread.o \
        build/moc_mainwindowimpl.o
DIST          = /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/common/g++.conf \
        /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/common/unix.conf \
        /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/common/linux.conf \
        /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/qconfig.pri \
        /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/qt_functions.prf \
        /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/qt_config.prf \
        /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/exclusive_builds.prf \
        /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/default_pre.prf \
        /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/debug.prf \
        /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/default_post.prf \
        /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/warn_on.prf \
        /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/qt.prf \
        /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/unix/thread.prf \
        /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/moc.prf \
        /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/resources.prf \
        /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/uic.prf \
        /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/yacc.prf \
        /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/lex.prf \
        myPico.pro
QMAKE_TARGET  = myPico
DESTDIR       = bin/
TARGET        = bin/myPico

first: all
####### Implicit rules

.SUFFIXES: .o .c .cpp .cc .cxx .C

.cpp.o:
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o "$@" "$

Build output:

Build (make)...
g++ -c -pipe -g -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -Ibuild -Ibuild -o build/mainwindowimpl.o src/mainwindowimpl.cpp
In file included from /usr/include/qt4/qwt_plot.h:17
,
                 from build/ui_mainwindow.h:29,
                 from src/mainwindowimpl.h:5,
                 from src/mainwindowimpl.cpp:1:
/usr/include/qt4/qwt_array.h:25:23: error: qmemarray.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /usr/include/qt4/qwt_marker.h:20,
                 from /usr/include/qt4/qwt_plot.h:23,
                 from build/ui_mainwindow.h:29,
                 from src/mainwindowimpl.h:5,
                 from src/mainwindowimpl.cpp:1:
/usr/include/qt4/qwt_text.h:20:29: error: qsimplerichtext.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /usr/include/qt4/qwt_plot.h:24,
                 from build/ui_mainwindow.h:29,
                 from src/mainwindowimpl.h:5,
                 from src/mainwindowimpl.cpp:1:
/usr/include/qt4/qwt_legend.h:16:25: error: qscrollview.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /usr/include/qt4/qwt_legend.h:25,
                 from /usr/include/qt4/qwt_plot.h:24,
                 from build/ui_mainwindow.h:29,
                 from src/mainwindowimpl.h:5,
                 from src/mainwindowimpl.cpp:1:
/usr/include/qt4/qwt_plot_dict.h:15:22: error: qintdict.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /usr/include/qt4/qwt_plot.h:25,
                 from build/ui_mainwindow.h:29,
                 from src/mainwindowimpl.h:5,
                 from src/mainwindowimpl.cpp:1:
/usr/include/qt4/qwt_plot_printfilter.h:16:24: error: qvaluelist.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /usr/include/qt4/qwt_dimap.h:14,
                 from /usr/include/qt4/qwt_grid.h:15,
                 from /usr/include/qt4/qwt_plot.h:18,
                 from build/ui_mainwindow.h:29,
                 from src/mainwindowimpl.h:5,
                 from src/mainwindowimpl.cpp:1:
/usr/include/qt4/qwt_math.h: In function ‘void qwtShiftArray(T*, int, int)’:
/usr/include/qt4/qwt_math.h:162: error: there are no arguments to ‘QABS’ that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of ‘QABS’ must be available
/usr/include/qt4/qwt_math.h:162: note: (if you use ‘-fpermissive’, G++ will accept your code, but allowing the use of an undeclared name is deprecated)
In file included from /usr/include/qt4/qwt_grid.h:16,
                 from /usr/include/qt4/qwt_plot.h:18,
                 from build/ui_mainwindow.h:29,
                 from src/mainwindowimpl.h:5,
                 from src/mainwindowimpl.cpp:1:
/usr/include/qt4/qwt_scldiv.h: At global scope:
/usr/include/qt4/qwt_scldiv.h:128: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘QMemArray’ with no type
/usr/include/qt4/qwt_scldiv.h:128: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘’
/usr/include/qt4/qwt_plot_dict.h:22: error: declaration of ‘class QwtSeqDict’
/usr/include/qt4/qwt_plot_dict.h: In constructor ‘QwtCurveDict::QwtCurveDict()’:
/usr/include/qt4/qwt_plot_dict.h:66: error: ‘setAutoDelete’ was not declared in this scope
/usr/include/qt4/qwt_plot_dict.h: At global scope:
/usr/include/qt4/qwt_plot_dict.h:70: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class QwtSeqDict’
/usr/include/qt4/qwt_plot_dict.h:22: error: declaration of ‘class QwtSeqDict’
/usr/include/qt4/qwt_plot_dict.h: In constructor ‘QwtMarkerDict::QwtMarkerDict()’:
/usr/include/qt4/qwt_plot_dict.h:72: error: ‘setAutoDelete’ was not declared in this scope
/usr/include/qt4/qwt_plot_dict.h: At global scope:
/usr/include/qt4/qwt_plot_dict.h:75: error: expected initializer before ‘’
/usr/include/qt4/qwt_plot_dict.h:22: error: declaration of ‘class QwtSeqDict’
/usr/include/qt4/qwt_legend.h:31: error: expected initializer before ‘

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uhh well mysteriously the issue just up and disappeared without me doing a single thing.