# How do I use the bootstrap and configure commands in Ubuntu?

Tags: qt, console, terminal, ubuntu-10.04

I am trying to solve a problem getting QDevelop to build code given to me from another workstation and I am getting all kinds of errors which I posted a question about but havn't received any responses. See: [QDevelop Qt IDE in Ubuntu 10.04 LTS Lucid Lynx qwt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4315843/qdevelop-qt-ide-in-ubuntu-10-04-lts-lucid-lynx-qwt)

I found someone having the same problem and I don't understand their solution. See: http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/202124

> Greetings,
>
> I removed libqwt-dev and did a .bootstrap and .configure and make and
> all is now well.
>
> Rob

My question is how do I use the .bootstrap command (./bootstrap)? And what the heck does it do for that matter? I can't find anything when I Google it.

While I am at it what does .configure (./configure?) do and how do I use it also?

I am running Ubuntu 10.04 Lucid Lynx

Thanks,
DemiSheep

Comment: That's probably not ".configure", but "./configure" (same for bootstrap). So I'd try "./bootstrap && ./configure && make". bootstrap is rather unusual, configure is the standard script to, well, configure your build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched to another IDE and OS's. :)